# What is this white fitting inline with my showerhead?

Tags: plumbing

I just got a new apartment and am going to replace my shower head as it's too low. I noticed that it has a white plastic fitting on it that comes before the shower head. I'm not to sure what it's for. Maybe someone can enlighten me?

[image]

Comment: Shower filter maybe?

Comment: It's a "Gimmick"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably a charcoal filter. Probably disgusting (people put them in, change the filter a few times, and then get bored of buying the filters, which turn into a gross mess as often as not.) Or the filters become unavailable since these are not exactly a standard item.

I'd strongly suggest removing it; if you want to keep it and can find filters for it, at least take it off and clean it throughly and replace the filter.

Looks like perhaps this one:
[image]

Comment: Note that removing the filter will significantly raise the shower head which is now too low.